# Is there something useful for third boundary condition on Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

There is a following task for a friend of mine to make:

$$-\Delta u=f,x\in(0,X),y\in(0,Y)\\-u_x+\alpha(y)u\Bigr|_{x=0}=g(y)\\u\Bigr|_{x=X}=c(y)\\u\Bigr|_{y=0}=a(x)\\u\Bigr|_{y=Y}=b(x)$$

She needs to make a program using biconjugate gradient method to solve the problem.She managed to implement the method but I don't know what matrix should she use and how does she need to enter it in Matlab.

I would appreciate you if you helped me with the matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of equations will be the same as the one discussed in the Wikipedia article ["Discrete Poisson equation"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Poisson_equation). To enter it into Matlab, I would suggest looking into the [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) command. (This function uses the "sparse matrix" format, which will significantly speed up calculations involving large matrices/fine discretizations.)